Color Excel chart data labels by categories for data arranged in two columns
The following code colors the chart data labels according to the categories and values arranged in two rows.

row 1 = category
row 2 = value

How can I make the code work for data arranged in two columns?

column A = category
column B = value

Replacing
Dim categoryColorRow As Long
Dim valueColorRow As Long
categoryColorRow = 1 
valueColorRow = 2
colIndex = 2 

with
Dim categoryColorCol As Long
Dim valueColorCol As Long
categoryColorCol = 1 
valueColorCol = 2 
colIndex = 2 

does not change the behavior of the code.
This is the whole routine for rows:
Sub Labels_SourceROWS()
  Dim p As Point
  Dim CatValueLength As Variant
  Dim dls As DataLabels
  Dim length As Long
  Dim labelItems As Variant
  Dim categoryColorRow As Long
  Dim valueColorRow As Long
  Dim colIndex As Long
  Dim color As Long
  Dim valueText As String
  Dim percentText As String
  Dim startPos As Long
  categoryColorRow = 1 
  valueColorRow = 2 
  colIndex = 2 
  With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
      .HasDataLabels = True
      With .DataLabels
          .ShowValue = True
          .ShowCategoryName = True
          .ShowPercentage = True
          .Separator = vbLf
          .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = False
          .NumberFormat = "#.##0,00;- #.##0,00"
          .Position = xlLabelPositionBestFit
          .Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
          .Font.Size = 8
      End With
      For Each p In .Points
          labelItems = Split(p.DataLabel.Text, vbLf)
          labelItems(1) = Format(Replace(labelItems(1), ".", ","), "0.00")
          labelItems(2) = Format(Replace(labelItems(2), ".", ","), "0.00%")
          With p.DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange
              'load datalabel
              .Text = labelItems(0) & vbLf & labelItems(1) & vbLf & labelItems(2)
              startPos = 1
              length = Len(labelItems(0)) 'Category
              color = ActiveSheet.Cells(categoryColorRow, colIndex).Font.color
              .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Bold = True
              .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = color
              'Value
              color = ActiveSheet.Cells(valueColorRow, colIndex).Font.color
              startPos = startPos + length + 1
              length = Len(labelItems(1))
              .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Bold = True
              .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = color
              'Percentage
              color = ActiveSheet.Cells(valueColorRow, colIndex).Font.color
              startPos = startPos + length + 1
              length = Len(labelItems(2))
              .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Bold = False
              .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = color
          End With
          colIndex = colIndex + 1
      Next
  End With
End Sub



Cells(valueColorRow, colIndex) and Cells(valueColorRow, colIndex) point to wrong cells.
colIndex is derived from chart series formula.

Sub Labels_SourceCOLUMNS()
   Dim p As Point
   Dim CatValueLength As Variant
   Dim dls As DataLabels
   Dim length As Long
   Dim labelItems As Variant
   Dim categoryColorRow As Long
   Dim valueColorCol As Long
   Dim colIndex As Long
   Dim color As Long
   Dim valueText As String
   Dim percentText As String
   Dim startPos As Long
   categoryColorRow = 1
   valueColorCol = 2
   ' colIndex = 2
'   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
'    Dim s As Series
'    Set s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
'    Stop
   With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
       colIndex = Range(Split(.Formula, ",")(1)).Column
       categoryColorRow = Range(Split(.Formula, ",")(1)).Row ' **
       .HasDataLabels = True
       With .DataLabels
           .ShowValue = True
           .ShowCategoryName = True
           .ShowPercentage = True
           .Separator = vbLf
           .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
           .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = False
           .NumberFormat = "0,0000"
           .Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
           .Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
           .Font.Size = 10
       End With
       For Each p In .Points
            startPos = 1
           labelItems = Split(p.DataLabel.Text, vbLf)
           'labelItems(1) = Format(Replace(labelItems(1), ".", ","), "0.00") 'no need
           labelItems(2) = Format(Replace(labelItems(2), ".", ","), "0.00%")
           With p.DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange
               ' load datalabel with text
               .Text = labelItems(0) & vbLf & labelItems(1) & vbLf & labelItems(2)
               length = Len(labelItems(0)) 'Category
               color = ActiveSheet.Cells(categoryColorRow, colIndex).Font.color
               .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Bold = True
               .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = color
               'Value
               color = ActiveSheet.Cells(categoryColorRow, colIndex + 1).Font.color
               startPos = startPos + length + 1
               length = Len(labelItems(1))
               .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Bold = True
               .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = color

               color = vbBlack
               startPos = startPos + length + 1
               length = Len(labelItems(2))
               .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Bold = False
               .Characters(startPos, length).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = color
           End With
           categoryColorRow = categoryColorRow + 1
       Next
   End With
End Sub




